# Firebase Read Only With No Authentication from App

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm starting with Firebase, and basically, i just want to store data in Firebase, and user from my app will only do a read only. From what i read so far, it seems that firebase only works with authentication, and i've read about anonymous authentication. But i don't see the advantage of being authenticated anonymously, since basically the user will never be upgraded to "permanent" user.

All i want is the user use my app (and only through my app) to get data without needing to authenticate.

What is the best way to achieve this ? Do i create a username and password, and use this for everyone in my app ?

Do i stay with anonymous authentication ? Since i will at first use the Firebase Spark Free, and it says that only 100 simultaneous connection for realtime database, do each creation of anonymous authentication will be considered as opening a connection all the time, thus limited my app to 100 connection/user only ? Is there a limitation for Spark Free in terms of anonymous connection ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase ***without*** authentication.  Some of the [Youtube tutorials](https://youtu.be/Bd4-6pnjjd8?t=6m9s) on the official Firebase channel even go as far as to show you how to disable authentication on the Firebase Database and Storage.  Only disable `read` authentication for production purposes.

[Storage Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start).

[Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart).

Comment: Thank you, i might not be clear enough on my demand, i only want user to be able to read data only using my app.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Watch the youtube tutorial I linked to, you don't need to use Authentication at all if you set it up correctly (for read only even).  As for the database, it's by connection, not authenticated connection.  So 100 unauthenticated connections are the same as 100 anonymous authenticated.  The realtime database is cached locally for offline use, so I suspect that it's 100 concurrent connections.

Comment: Why should I disable read when I want users to read data from Firebase without authentication? Shouldn't I enable read and disable write?